# Fix 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, php-fpm, wordpress, digital-ocean

I have Nginx running on Ubuntu server (digital ocean), I've setup LEMP stack for hosting the Wordpress website. I'm getting **501 Bad Gateway** when I try to reach website using the IP address.

I see this errors in the log:

```
2022/05/24 14:43:52 [error] 199802#199802: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 212.58.120.29, server: localhost, request: "GET /ttemp.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "46.101.238.240"
2022/05/24 14:43:52 [error] 199802#199802: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 212.58.120.29, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "46.101.238.240", referrer: "https://46.101.238.240/ttemp.php"
```

And here's my Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /var/www/ssl/default.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/ssl/default.key;
    server_name localhost mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

    root /var/www/mydomain.com;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log info;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

And my UFW status:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx HTTPS                ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
2222                       ALLOW       Anywhere
3306                       ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
9000                       ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Nginx HTTPS (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
2222 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3306 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
9000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Show the `lsof -P -n -i :9000` output, please.

Comment: `lsof -P -n -i :9000` command gives no output

Comment: That means the PHP-FPM daemon doesn't listen TCP port 9000. Check the default pool configuration, most likely it is listen on some UNIX socket instead.

Comment: please answer the questions else it will stay open forever.